# How can I increase height of a silverlight popup without increasing the height of the object in HTML

Tags: html, css, silverlight

I have a silverlight object in my HTML page. We have a constraint that the browser should never have a vertical scroll, the entire page should fit in the browser window. As a result, we have given fixed height to the silverlight object element.

```
<div style="width: 99%; margin-left: 5px;">
    <object id="ClaimsGrid" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" style="height: 283px; width: 100%;">
        <param name="InitParams" value="ControlName=ReviewStockistClaims,ServiceUrl=@Model.ServiceUrl" />
        <param name="windowless" value="true"/>
        <param name="source" value="@Url.Content("~/ClientBin/ReviewStockistClaims.xap")"/>
        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.60129.0" />
        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        <param name="onLoad" value="pluginLoaded" />
    </object>
</div>
```

This is how the plugin looks:

[image]

The 'Stockist Claim Details' window is a popup with a datagrid. The user wants us to fit 20 rows in the popup. However, if we increase the height of the popup, its top and bottom get cut off due to the fixed height of the object (283px). Is there any way I can increase the height of the popup such that -

1. It appears complete, and is not cut off.
2. The total height of the page doesn't increase.

Comment: Have you tried viewbox ?? Give height and width to viewbox and place your control inside it.

Comment: I agree with the viewbox control in silverlight, however the size of the characters might become too small to be readable.